# File Image size increases while uploading to firebase through expo image picker react native using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: image, firebase, react-native, expo

I am facing a very strange issue that my Image size increases while uploading to firebase.
I have logged the file size before uploading, it is showing the same size but after uploading the file size gets increased. Also the image is not corrupted. Please help..

Uploading to firebase code :

```
 async uploadImageAsync(uri, passedParameter, ItemName) {
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
      xhr.send(null);
    });

    const ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child("CategoryDescription" + "/" + passedParameter + "/" + ItemName);

    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

    blob.close();
    const downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return downloadUrl;
  }
```

**Pick Image code : **

```
 async _pickImage() {
    const { CAMERA, CAMERA_ROLL } = Permissions;
    const permissions = {
      [CAMERA]: await Permissions.askAsync(CAMERA),
      [CAMERA_ROLL]: await Permissions.askAsync(CAMERA_ROLL)
    };

    if (
      permissions[CAMERA].status === "granted" &&
      permissions[CAMERA_ROLL].status === "granted"
    ) {
      var pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        quality: 0.1
      });

      if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
        console.log(pickerResult);
        this.setState({
          itemImage: pickerResult.uri
        });
```

** On button pressed code**

```
  handleConfirmAddItems = () => {
    var passedParameter = this.params.item.key;
    const { ItemName, ItemPrice, ItemDesc, ItemWeight, itemImage } = this.state;


      {
        itemImage !== "" &&
          this._handleImagePicked(itemImage, passedParameter, ItemName);
      }

      writeUrlToDB(
        itemImage,
        passedParameter,
        ItemName,
        ItemDesc,
        ItemPrice,
        ItemWeight
      );
    }
  };
```

** handle image picked **

```
 async _handleImagePicked(itemImage, passedParameter, ItemName) {
    try {
      const uploadUrl = await this.uploadImageAsync(
        itemImage,
        passedParameter,
        ItemName
      );
      this.setState({ itemImage: uploadUrl });
      console.log("itemIma", uploadUrl);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert("Upload failed, sorry :(");
    }
  }
```

Please help.. I am in great stress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug in Image picker.. This is the issue in the case of iOS Simulator, in Android device its working fine : )

Comment: Issue is in iOS Device, not only in Simulator